# Querying by base type in EF4 Code-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have the following types:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double TopSpeed { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle {
    public int Doors { get; set; }
}

public class Motorcycle : Vehicle { 
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a code-first DBContext:

```
public MyDbContext: DbContext { 
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Motorcycle> Motorcycles { get; set; }
}
```

This works great if I query for a car or moto directly...

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
var cars = dbContext.Set<Car>().Where(x=> x.TopSpeed>10); // <-- THIS WORKS
```

But if I want a list of all vehicles, whether car or moto, I would like to do this:

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
var vehicles = dbContext.Set<Vehicle>().Where(x=> x.TopSpeed>10); // <-- THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

When I try the above code, I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The entity type Vehicle is not part
>   of the model for the current context.

That makes perfect sense... I didn't add Vehicle to the context. I added car and moto. At this point, I'm not sure what to do. I tried adding Vehicle to my context, but that combined the tables for car and moto into one Vehicle table. I definitely want a separate table for cars and motos (and possibly a table for the vehicle base properties as well). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: EF isn't my thing, but could you get a set via interface if you add it to the context, e.g. change `Vehicle` to `IVehicle`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a Vehicles Properties of type DBSet of `Vehicle` in your MyDbContext class.

```
public MyDbContext: DbContext { 
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Motorcycle> Motorcycles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { set; get; }
}
```

Now you can access all vehicles with the criteria like this

```
var vehicles = dbContext.Set<Vehicle>().Where(x=> x.TopSpeed>10);
```

Keep in mind that you should have a Key Property in your entity classes ( `ID` or `{ClassName}ID`). Otherwise it is going to give you a run time error! (Yes the code will compile.)

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public double TopSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT : As per the comment**

By Default Entity Framework will do a **Table Per Hierarchy**.All Data in the hierarchy is saved in a single table and it use the `Discriminator` column to identify which record belongs to which subtype. So As the result you will have one Vehicle table with columns same as properties of All your classes in the hierarchy with an extra column called "`Discriminator`". For a Record for Car, It will have the "Car" value inside the Discriminator column.

[image]

If you want to create Single table per each type, We will go for **Table Per Type**. Entity Framework will create a Table for the base class and seperate table for all child classes.

To make this happen, You can use Fluent API to override the configuration.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Cars");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Motorcycle>().ToTable("Motorcycles");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

And the output is

[image]

Now You should be able to query Your Vehicle Entries like this

```
 var vehicles = dbContext.Set<Vehicle>().Where(x => x.TopSpeed > 150).ToList();
```

And the result is here

[image]

Notice that the result contains both `MotorCycle` type and `Car` type.

Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx) to decide what Inheritance Strategy to use.

Comment: Correct. I forgot to include the id prop in my example.

Comment: Tried this and it combined my cars and motos into one table called vehicles. I want a table per type.

Comment: @NSGaga: Sometimes images make more sense. It is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving Vehicle its own context with just a DBSet? I think that might do it for you.

Comment: The query works when I do this, but the tables are smashed into one. Before it was table-per-type... not it's table-per-hierarchy.

Comment: So just to be clear you have a VehicleDbContext and a MyDbContext (with cars and moto) it still creates one table called Vehicle? What are you using to create the tables? Also, have you tried using the EDMX writer over it to make sure that the inheritence is exactly as you planned?

Answer (score 0):

Using a DataAnnotation.Schema.Table("TableName") entry, on the inherited class, triggers the creation of a new table for the inherited type (table-per-type) and eliminates the Discriminator field in the parent type table, without the need for the Fluent API code.